# Partner Community - Opportunity Data Not Displaying

Tags: visualforce, community, opportunity, partner-communities

I'm setting up a Partner Community (with VF pages) in my dev org , and I've run across a problem displaying opportunities on the community page.

Basically, the community is set up so that a "client" (a contact on an account) can log in and see the data for his or her account.  I've successfully displayed the data for a custom object, but the fields for the opportunity data is all blank.  I can't tell if I'm just doing something stupid or if there's a Salesforce restriction at play.

The service to get the opportunity data looks like this:

```
public static List<Opportunity> getOpps(Id accountId2) {
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>{};

    if  (accountId2 != null) {
        for (Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, Name, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accountId2]) { 
            oppList.add(opp);
        }
    }   

    return oppList;
}
```

Then, in the controller for my VF page I have this:

```
public AccountPageController(){
    oppList = PortalService.getOpps(contact.Account.Id);
}
```

And the code to display the data on the VF page looks like this:

```
    <h2>Opportunities</h2>
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat value="{!oppList}" var="opp">
            <li>
                {!opp.Name}, {!opp.Id}, {!opp.AccountId}
            </li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
```

I've also shared the opportunity with the "All Customer Portal Users" group, and I ran the query in the dev console to make sure that I was getting back some data.  On my VF page, it shows two bullet points (there are two opportunities, so that's good), but the field data is blank.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you check the Field Level Security for your profile?

Comment: Yes (even though I hadn't added any field-level security)...and here's a weird thing:  on the opportunity, the profile choices is a rather limited list (and doesn't include the custom profile that I created for the community), but on my custom object the profile list is quite lengthy and does include the custom profile I created.

Comment: I haven't completely wrapped my head around it but it's my understanding that `Portal User` licenses don't have access to all Standard objects (not sure if opportunities falls into this category), but it might explain why Opportunity doesn't appear under 'Standard Field-Level Security' options when viewing that profile?

Comment: That's what I was worried about, but according to this (Who Can See What in Communities): https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_visibility.htm&language=en_US , opportunities should be visible to external community users (if I understand it correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  The problem was that I had set up my community users with the Customer Community Plus User profile (actually, a clone thereof).  This profile did not have opportunities listed on it.  When I changed the profile to the Partner Community User (a clone thereof), the read/write settings for opportunities was available, and I was able to see opportunities.  I guess it's ultimately a Salesforce licensing issue -- if you want to allow the community users see opportunities, I'm guessing you need to get a partner community license.